# Converting 2 array data type columns into rows in Snowflake

Tags: arrays, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table of two columns both with the array data type. Their array size is the same (3 elements in an array). Each element in an array column is paired with the same-positioned element in another array column. I would like to know how to extract each element in both array columns and convert them into multiple rows using Snowflake.

This is how the table looks like

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| ["a","b","c"] | [1,2,3] |
| ["d","e","f"] | [4,5,6] |

I want to get the outcome like

| characters | numbers |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 3 |
| d | 4 |
| e | 5 |
| f | 6 |

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may use FLATTEN for this purpose:

```
select a1.VALUE, a2.VALUE from mytable,
LATERAL FLATTEN( col1 ) a1,
LATERAL FLATTEN( col2 ) a2
where a1.index = a2.index;

+-------+-------+
| VALUE | VALUE |
+-------+-------+
| "a"   |     1 |
| "b"   |     2 |
| "c"   |     3 |
| "d"   |     4 |
| "e"   |     5 |
| "f"   |     6 |
+-------+-------+
```

FLATTEN https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html